# Audio tag fails W3C validation - why?

Tags: html, audio, w3c-validation

I've set up a test page to demonstrate this, which can be viewed at 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/846812/html_audio_test/audio_test.html

The page source is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My audio test page</title>
  </head>        

  <body>
    <audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/846812/html_audio_test/cha-ching.wav" type="audio/wav" id="audio-cha-ching"></audio>
    <p>You should hear a "ka-ching" noise.</p>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){ 
        $("audio")[0].play();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When i validate this at http://validator.w3.org/check it complains:

*Error Line 9, Column 128: Attribute type not allowed on element audio at this point.*

But, i'm following the documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

So, why is it complaining?  Have I not properly defined my page as an html5 document?

Comment: Check out the w3schools page you linked once more. You're not actually following their documentation. Also see [the wonderful MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) for a more detailed overview of the tag and its allowed attributes.

Comment: @TotempaaltJ OMG you're right!  I think that i saw my version on a different W3C page :-{

Comment: The functionality on the page i've linked to is different to what i have, actually:  my existing one just plays the wav with no visible content to the user.  The version on the W3C page puts an audio player, with scrub bar, play button etc, on the page.  I don't want that, i just want to make the wav play with no user interaction, as soon as the dom ready block runs.

Comment: Don't confuse W3Schools with the W3C. The former is a third party site that gets a lot of reflected glory from having a similar name to the standards organisation.

Comment: @MaxWilliams read the MDN page I linked, it gives a lot more information and also tells you how to tackle that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering this myself for the benefit of anyone else who's as confused as i clearly was (Nigel Tufnel?) - this is the valid way to do it, and how to play the audio on demand with jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My audio test page</title>
  </head>        

  <body>
    <audio id="audio-cha-ching">
      <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/846812/html_audio_test/cha-ching.wav" type="audio/wav" >
    </audio>
    <p>You should hear a "ka-ching" noise.</p>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){ 
        $("#audio-cha-ching").trigger("play");
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```